# why 1 digit random numbers are also getting generated by the following code?

Tags: random, vb6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 100
    List1.AddItem (Int(100 * Rnd()))
    If ((Int(100 * Rnd())) >= 10) Then
        Print
    Else

    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the random numbers to range from 10 to 99, you need to calculate them a bit differently. There are 90 different possible values, so that is what you multiply Rnd() by. Then you add the minimum value, which is 10:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim x As Integer
   For x = 1 To 100
      List1.AddItem(Int(90 * Rnd()) + 10)
   Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have mistyped this code, as I don't see what you are printing.  Also, in general you should probably assign your random number to a temp variable.  As is, the random number you are adding to the list is not the same as the one in your if block.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's because you're generating a random number once, and adding it to `List1`; then you generate *another, different* random number and conditionally print it.

You are not doing any filtering on what numbers get added to `List1`, and I'm not quite sure what you're printing (I'm not a VB guy).

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be in two parts.  First, you are adding a number to your list that is different then the one you are comparing.

The second is that you are using Rnd in the wrong manner. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(VS.80).aspx for usage but basically, the way your code is set you are generating a number between 0 and 100. Because rnd returns a single.

What's happening is that your basically doing 100 * 0.5 which returns you 50 or 100 * 0.01 which returns you 1.

If you want a lower bound of 100 you have to do it like this.

```
CInt(Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd() + lowerbound))
```

Also, please don't forget to call Randomize() before using Rnd